# gradle signning with different flavour with diiferent LICENSE_KEY android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have many productflavour in android. I need to sign in and upload apk in play store i had many research but nothing found. Only thing is found keypass,
keypass but i need to use different encrypted private key in different account. I am new in gradle so if you Know please help.Thanks in advance

My project Structure

```
<>src
  + common
    +java
    +res
  + Fruits
    +java
    +res
  + Vegetablies
    + java
    + res
 ....... so many
```

play console key ="eb10fe***************7c7c9df7150*****************************************"

play console key ="55899fe***************9090w97df7150*****************************************"

i have so many different key to different flavours

```
    signingConfigs {
            Fruits {
             BASE_64_LICENSE_KEY = "****************************************"
             APK_SIGNATURE_PRODUCTION = "**********"
            }

            vegetables {
               BASE_64_LICENSE_KEY = "****************************************"
             APK_SIGNATURE_PRODUCTION = "**********"
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
                debug {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
                release {
                    // When you compile an APK as release, your resources and IV keys will be safeguarded
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }

                flavorDimensions "default"
                productFlavors {
                    Fruits{
                        applicationId "oos.fruits"
                       signingConfig signingConfigs.fruits
                    }
                    vegetables{
                        applicationId "oos.vegetabes"
                    }
                }

            }
            sourceSets {
                main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
                Fruits.assets.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
                Fruits{
                    res.srcDirs = ['/src/Fruits/res']
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue/error you are facing?

Generate the keystore and use keystore details in build.gradle to sign your app.
Follow the steps mentioned in https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

signing config details in app/build.gradle.

```
signingConfigs {
        fruit {
            keyAlias 'abcd'
            keyPassword 'ABCD02018#033'
            storeFile file('keystore/abcd.keystore')
            storePassword 'ABCD02018#033'
        }

        //add another block for new variant
    }

    productFlavors {
        Fruit {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.fruit

        }
```

Comment: thansk sir .. It would great help...can i ask you some more question

Comment: How to declare a variable in gradle and need to change if there is condition..And how to use the varibale in another file...For example  I have gradle file in which i delcare the variable something like that                                           
    buildConfigField "String", "CheckLicence", "\"foo\""        ..... can we another way to declare the variable and if i want to change variable value and assign some new how can we do and another thing is that how can we print the variable................  I used println Checklicense it giver error of "unkown Property "

Comment: println shall work. look into this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:sending_your_own_log_messages                                           For variable declaration and use refer this                                                    https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code